# Alphabetical (A-Z) list with international chars in PHP

Tags: php, alphabetical

Is there way to generate alphabetical list in PHP but with other chars.

For instance croatian alphabet is `A,B,C,Č,Ć,D,Đ,DŽ,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,LJ,M,N,NJ,O,P,R,S,Š,T,U,V,Z,Ž`

And in german alphabet there are `ÖÄÜ` and so on

This php function works only on regular English Alphabet

```
$alphabet = range('A', 'Z');
```

Comment: You are looking for something that takes about 30 characters to type, and want to have it done with an expression taking about ... 12 characters? Is it worth it?

Comment: Do you need it for sorting? In this case use iconv() with //TRANSLIT to convert the international chars 'ö' to ascii 'oe'.